# Copy text from a table on a webpage into string in C#

Tags: c#

I need to make a list like this: List>
And I want to copy contents from a table on this [website](http://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-afrikaans-words/) .

More specificly, I want the word in languange 1 in the first string and the word in languange 2 in the second string, and then do that for every word in that table.

I want to be able to do that by just entering a url because I want to do this for more languanges.

It`s probably pretty easy but I have never done something like this before so sorry if this question is trivial. 
Also, please excuse my english scince it`s not my first language.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out HTMLAgility pack for C#. it is a powerful tool to crawl Web content as well.  you can find enough information over here https://html-agility-pack.net/from-web

Comment: a simple link is not a good enough answer, see the answer for "AngleSharp" as an idea of what an answer reccomending a library should look like

Comment: I appreciate your view but bare in mind he didn't have code issue to begin with, he simply didn't know which tool to use and here the link gives enough documentation with code examples to make his problem solved. simply writing pieces of codes for no reason for others is not always the best solution. now with your desired version in answer above a simple copy paste without understanding the issue, his problem will be solved with possible learning outcome of 0 for him.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AngleSharp

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
    List<WordCls> wordList = new List<WordCls>();

    IBrowsingContext context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader());
    Url url = Url.Create("http://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-afrikaans-words");
    IDocument doc = await context.OpenAsync(url);
    IElement tableElement = doc.QuerySelector("table");
    var trs = tableElement.QuerySelectorAll("tr");

    foreach (IElement tr in trs.Next(selector: null))
    {
        var tds = tr.QuerySelectorAll("td");
        WordCls word = new WordCls
        {
            Number = Convert.ToInt32(tds[0].Text()),
            African = tds[1].Text(),
            English = tds[2].Text()
        };

        wordList.Add(word);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(wordList.Count);

}
```

---

```
public class WordCls
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string African { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
}
```